# If Linux server is down (no response on ping command), is it possible to reboot the server using ssh?

Tags: server, ssh

My server is not responding and even the ping command shows 100% loss. How can I reboot it via ssh?

I've come to know about **sudo reboot** command, but I'm not even being able to login via ssh since the server is down. Any solution. please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to physically login and reboot.